# Como renombrar elementos de un arreglo en php

Tags: php

Deseo renombrar los valores de un arreglo en php, cambiar este arreglo:

```
$value('valor1','valor2');
```

a este otro:

```
$value('v1','v2');
```

Comment: Hola @wink. Por favor describe más sobre el problema. Por ejemplo, si cuál es la tu función de mapeo a aplicar a los elementos del arreglo, si la "conversión" es solo tomando el primer y último caracter del elemento, o qué consideraciones deben haber.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar **[array_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)** para reemplazar valores de elementos dentro del array :

```
<?php
  $value = array('valor1', 'valor2');
  //aquí reemplazas los valores del array!
  $replacements = array(0 => 'v1', 1 => 'v2');
  $final_array = array_replace($value, $replacements);
  print_r($final_array);
?>
```

De acuerdo al script anterior, tendríamos inicialmente :

```
Array
(
    [0] => valor1
    [1] => valor2
)
```

y reemplazando los valores dentro del array mediante **[array_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)** tendremos como valores finales:

```
Array
(
    [0] => v1
    [1] => v2
)
```

Puedes ver el [ejemplo aquí](https://ideone.com/c3UsYi).